# OneDrive file browser authentication issues "GraphError: Unable to retrieve user's mysite URL."

Tags: reactjs, azure, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

We are working on a request for embedding OneDrive file browser within a web application.
The code we are using comes directly from the examples provided on github.

Here is our client side code:

```
import React from "react"
import logo from "./logo.svg"
import "./App.css"

import { GraphFileBrowser } from "@microsoft/file-browser"

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <GraphFileBrowser getAuthenticationToken={this.getAuthenticationToken} />
    )
  }

  getAuthenticationToken() {
    return new Promise(resolve =>
      resolve(
        "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub25jZSI6ImtkT..."
      )
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

This is 100% based on examples provided by MS.
As we don't want the users to have to login using oAuth, we are getting a token server side using MicrosoftGraph following this official guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow.
We have of course also setup the app in Azure, based on all the requirements defined above.

So once we insert the token in our react component, we just get an error: `GraphError: Unable to retrieve user's mysite URL.`

When we test the same client side app however with a token generated via the OAUTH user token, the file browser will

Comment: Have you navigated to the OneDrive page of this user? does it render correctly?